# Same eventlistener to different titanium objects

Tags: event-handling, titanium-mobile

Is it possible in Titanium to have one eventListener for 2 objects? I.e. I have 2 buttons and i want same actions on click.

Should i create: `button1.addEventListener` and `button2.addEventListener`?

**Or**

i can make something like:

```
var array = [button1, button2];
array.addEventListener... ?
```

**Or**

maybe i can make something like `object.addEventListener('button1_clicked','button2_clicked', function() {});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You should create event listeners for each object. For that you should create a function and you can use it to handle your events. Please have a look at following example

```
button1.addEventListener('click', showMessage); //Adding event handlers to button1
button2.addEventListener('click', showMessage); //Adding event handlers to button2

function showMessage(event){
    alert("You have clicked " + event.source.title + " button");
    //event.source denotes the control which fired the event
}
```

Here I have used the same functon `showMessage()` to handle your click event. On click of each button, it will display a message which tells the button which you clicked.

If you have many buttons which is used for same purposes, you can try the following

```
var button = [];
var totalButtons = 10;//I'm assuming you have 10 buttons in your screen
for(var index=0; index<totalButtons;index++){
   button[i] = Ti.UI.createButton({
       title : 'Button ' + (index+1),
       width : 20,
       height: 50,
   });

   button[index].addEventListener('click', showMessage);
   win.add(button[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the same function to each object. For example, assuming you have two buttons named `button1` and `button2`:

```
function myEventListener(e) {
    alert('Clicked button with title '+e.source.title);
}
button1.addEventListener('click', myEventListener);
button2.addEventListener('click', myEventListener);
```